# Magento 2: Create Invoice or Shipment with REST API with different date

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, invoice

I want to post a shipment and/or invoice into Magento 2 but put a different date than today's date using the HTTP Rest API. Is this possible and how would I accomplish this? When I include the created_at field in the API body, it does not reflect that date.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to generate the shipment/invoice and then you can all another REST API to modify the date of shipments/invioces.